# audio error when concatenating clips using ffmpeg

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video-conversion, concatenation

I'm trying to do the following:

- cut an input video into segments and convert these segments in the same step
- concatenate the transcoded segments back together in an output file

The steps that I'm going through are:

1) create the segments and transcode them

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00 -t 10 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac -f mpegts segment0.ts
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 10 -t 10 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac -f mpegts segment1.ts
```

etc.

2) concatenate the segments using the Concat Demuxer

```
printf "file '%s'\n" ./*.ts > mylist.txt

ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -vcodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
```

This works fine (or at least seems to work fine as I can't hear or see any problems in the output file) with 1 testing video I'm using (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x76VEPXYaI0)

But there are some audible glitches at the glue points between segments when I try another testing video - http://trailers.divx.com/divx_prod/profiles/Helicopter_DivXHT_ASP.divx. In this one, ffmpeg already shows an error message during the segment cutting and transcoding:

> [mp3 @ 0x297d220] Header missing
>   Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input

Does anyone know if these audio glitches at the glue points can be avoided, if it's just this input file and its audio being weird or if it's likely a general problem with my method?

Thanks for your help.

Console output of segment/transcode command:

```
ffmpeg -i helicopter.divx -ss 00 -t 10 -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac -f mpegts segment0.ts
ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 23 2014 18:58:08 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/tobi/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-    I/home/tobi/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/tobi/ffmpeg_build/lib --    bindir=/home/tobi/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-    libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-    libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, avi, from 'helicopter.divx':
  Duration: 00:01:48.11, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4192 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (DX50 / 0x30355844), yuv420p, 720x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 30:17], 3991     kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 23.98 tbn, 30k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : Video 
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16p, 192 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio 
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] profile High, level 3.0
Output #0, mpegts, to 'segment0.ts':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.43.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 720x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 30:17], q=-1--1, 23.98     fps, 90k tbn, 23.98 tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : Video 
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      title           : Audio 
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg4 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp3 (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  240 fps= 12 q=28.0 Lsize=     974kB time=00:00:10.00 bitrate= 797.6kbits/s    
video:709kB audio:158kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:     12.433780%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] frame I:2     Avg QP:13.73  size:  5558
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] frame P:109   Avg QP:21.15  size:  5161
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] frame B:129   Avg QP:21.30  size:  1181
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] consecutive B-frames: 17.5% 24.2% 25.0% 33.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] mb I  I16..4: 56.3% 37.6%  6.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] mb P  I16..4:  5.7% 11.7%  0.6%  P16..4: 29.5% 10.9%  5.9%  0.0%  0.0%        skip:35.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] mb B  I16..4:  1.0%  2.2%  0.1%  B16..8: 19.3%  3.9%  0.8%  direct: 0.8%      skip:72.0%  L0:39.1% L1:50.6% BI:10.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] 8x8 transform intra:63.0% inter:69.7%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 29.6% 40.0% 6.6% inter: 10.2% 12.2% 1.8%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] i16 v,h,dc,p: 24% 33% 10% 33%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 30% 32%  2%  3%  2%  3%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 20% 26%  4% 11%  5%  6%  3%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] i8c dc,h,v,p: 62% 22% 13%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] Weighted P-Frames: Y:16.5% UV:8.3%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] ref P L0: 68.7% 13.1% 14.4%  3.7%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] ref B L0: 80.9% 18.2%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] ref B L1: 87.5% 12.5%
[libx264 @ 0x2408220] kb/s:580.21
```

Console output of Concat Demuxer (I left out the *creating list in .txt file* step)

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -vcodec copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc output.mp4
ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 23 2014 18:58:08 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/tobi/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-    I/home/tobi/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/tobi/ffmpeg_build/lib --    bindir=/home/tobi/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-    libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-    libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 89.100 / 52. 89.100
  libavcodec     55. 66.100 / 55. 66.100
  libavformat    55. 43.100 / 55. 43.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.101 / 55. 13.101
  libavfilter     4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[concat @ 0x1ff0c20] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, concat, from 'mylist.txt':
  Duration: 00:00:00.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p, 720x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR     30:17], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 47.95 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 124 kb/s
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.43.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 720x408 [SAR 1:1 DAR 30:17],     q=2-31, 23.98 fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (libfdk_aac) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 128     kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc55.66.100 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libfdk_aac @ 0x21ee7e0] Queue input is backward in time.38 bitrate= 388.3kbits/s    
[mp4 @ 0x21ec7a0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 442367, current: 441650;     changing to 442368. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
frame=  480 fps=289 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1805kB time=00:00:20.06 bitrate= 736.6kbits/s    
video:1470kB audio:316kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead:     1.049592%
```

I tested it with another video and got the audio gaps between concatenated segments in that one too. These gaps are visible when I open the file in Audacity.

Comment: Please include the complete `ffmpeg` console output for each command. You added the [tag:segmentation-fault] tag, but are you experiencing a segmentation fault?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out, I took out that tag. I added the console output above, hope in the right way.

Comment: See [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/682534/110524). Usage of the (a)trim and concat filters is probably the best solution in this case since you are re-encoding anyway.

Comment: Works for me. I don't get the error you talk about with the same file and I can hear no audio clicking. Make sure to try a recent version of ffmpeg too. 2.2. is a little outdated already. You can get a static build here: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: I compiled the latest ffmpeg build for Ubuntu, ran the same sequence of commands from above again on the helicopter video and noticed that the segments created using the -ss and transcode command from 1) above have a small bit of silent audio at the start, not sure what causes this. I then followed the answer from the other question you linked to and used the trim/concat combo, this led to an output video without audio gaps, thanks!

Comment: Now one more question - can I use the same command (probably with modifications) so that I can extract the segments, transcode them from whatever they are to H.264 and AAC, then concatenate them and output them as .ts? That part is missing from the trim/concat combo so far. I mean the /-vcodec libx264 -acodec libfdk_aac -f mpegts/ for each segment before they get concatenated. The reason is that I'm trying to have these segments transcoded in parallel, then put back together in an output file.

Comment: Can you post a new question for that please? Just include the command you're using now and what specifically you need as output. (note that you need to mention users with @ in the comment thread – otherwise they don't get a reply notification)