# Batch merge sets of video files?

Tags: windows, video, batch, merge

I have 158 folders, each containing 5-15 video files that are each a few minutes long. I would like to merge all of the videos into one video per folder, and delete the rest.

The folders are named as dates in a certain year with gaps between them (`01.11`, `01.12`, `01.13`, `01.14`, `01.18` ... `01.28`, `02.01`, etc.), and the files in them are named as follows:

`ds_AAAAA_BB_CCC_480.mp4`

The first blank (`AAAAA`) is a number that is the same for all files in that folder. For folder `01.11`, the number is `03075`, and it goes up by one for each folder after that.

The second blank (`BB`) is the order of the files, from 01 to however many files are in that folder.

The third blank (`CCC`) is a set of three letters that varies per file and can be ignored.

For a couple examples, the first file in the first folder (`01.11`) is `ds_03075_01_nws_480.mp4`. The last (7th) file in the fourth folder (`01.14`) is `ds_03078_07_zen_480.mp4`.

Ideally, I'd like the new files to be in a separate folder (just to make it easy to delete the old files), and named in a format like `01_11.mp4`, `01_12.mp4`, and so on, but any naming convention there would be fine.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to go about this?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Windows 8, 64-bit. Sorry, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been merging (concatenating) videos lately, and I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/681885/how-can-i-remove-multiple-segments-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg#863451) very useful. To start with, install [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) and make sure it's on your path.

You have to make a list of files for each dir that consists of a text file in this format:

```
file `file1.mp4`
file `file2.mp4`
file `file3.mp4`
```

Then you just run ffmpeg with this syntax:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i filelist.txt -c copy merged.mp4
```

I was constructing these by hand for a few files, but for 158 folders you'll want some automation. The approach I'd take is probably using the `FOR` command in the Windows command prompt. You can generate the file lists using something like:

```
for /r %f in (*.mp4) do echo file '%~nxf' >>%~dpf\concat.txt
```

This recursively (`/r`) scans the MP4 files in the current folder and all subfolders, and echoes (prints) the name and extension (that's the `nx` bit) to a separate file in each subfolder (the `dp` bit gets the drive letter and path). The `>>` bit makes it append the filename to the list, so if you run this twice you'll get a duplicated list. So delete any `concat.txt` files before running the command.

Then you want to run ffmpeg on each of those. You'll need something like:

```
for /d %f in (*) do cd %~ff & ffmpeg -f concat -i concat.txt -c copy ..\merged\%~nf.mp4
```

For each directory (`/d`), change into it (`cd`), and (`&`) run ffmpeg, generating a result file that goes in the "merged" folder of the top-level folder, and is named after the folder name.

Not tested, so use at your own risk. (Although it won't delete or overwrite anything without asking.)

Comment: Backtick around filename.mp4 didn't work for me, but single quotes did. So use 'file1.mp4' instead of `file1.mp4` if you run into 'unsafe file name' errors.

Comment: I had to add `-safe 0` before `-i` to solve the "unsafe file name" error. Got this from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996925/ffmpeg-concat-unsafe-file-name#comment65345487_38996925

Comment: The last command to iterate through each subfolder wasn't working for me for a number of reasons, so I had to edit it to `for /d /r %f in (*) do cd %~ff & ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i filelist.txt -c copy merged.mp4`

Answer (score 0):

I made this batch script if this still helps. https://github.com/jeromerobles/video_merge

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1230070)