# FFmpeg mp4 to webm, make a 10 second compilation based on length

Tags: ffmpeg

Let's say I have `input.mp4` which is 12 minutes long. I'd like to take 4 times 2.5 seconds from the input to one file, `output.webm`.

So, first 2.5 seconds at 2.5 minute mark, second 2.5 seconds at 5 minute mark, then the same at 7.5 second mark and finally last 2.5 seconds on the 10 minute mark. Then output it all to same `output.webm` file.

And if this is possible, is this also possible so that if the `input.mp4` length changes, I'd get those 4 parts from based to the length instead of them always being standard 2.5, 5, 7.5 and 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Creating a compilation clip based on cuts in a video using ffmpeg

*Please note the following is based on [ptQa's answer](https://superuser.com/a/682534/461558) with modifications, so it deserves an upvote if this answer is useful.*

The following `fffmpeg` incantation will give you a 10 second VP8 webm with cuts at the 2.5,5 7.5 and 10 minute mark:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex " \
[0:v]trim=start=150:duration=2.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[av];\
[0:a]atrim=start=150:duration=2.5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[aa];\
[0:v]trim=start=300:duration=2.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[bv];\
[0:a]atrim=start=300:duration=2.5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ba];\
[0:v]trim=start=450:duration=2.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[cv];\
[0:a]atrim=start=450:duration=2.5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[ca];\
[0:v]trim=start=900:duration=2.5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[dv];\
[0:a]atrim=start=900:duration=2.5,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[da];\
[av][aa][bv][ba][cv][ca][dv][da]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
-map [outv] -map [outa] -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis  out.webm
```

This makes four uses each of [trim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#trim) and [atrim](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#atrim) filters, and finally combines the subclips using the [concat](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) filter.

The encoding options are what are suggested by the [`libvpx` encoding guide from the FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP8).

### Bonus: variable trims based on input length

This is doable with a bit of scripting, using `ffprobe` to get the duration, eg:

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
```

This returns the clip length in seconds, which can be divided by 5 and then multiplied by 1, 2 3 and 4 to give positions of four equally-spaced cuts respectively.

### Note on performance

While generating the clip this way is neat in that it exactly excises the subclips from the input video, it is ***slow***.

A quicker approach would be to use [input seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) and a stream copy to make the subclips, before joining those together and encoding.

However, if you need exact durations, or performance isn't an issue, using a bunch of `trim` filters will do the job just fine.

## Script to generate the clip using `trim` for any input length and any number of cuts/subclips

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# clip.sh - create a clip of short sequences of a passed-in media file
# takes one argument, the input file
# can customise number of cuts, total length of clip
# clips will be evenly-spaced in input file

SUBCLIPS=4 # number of clips to make up clip
OUTPUTLENGTH=10 # output file length, in seconds
OUTPUTFILE=out.webm # name

cliplength=$(echo "$OUTPUTLENGTH/$SUBCLIPS"| bc -l)

if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        videofile="$1"
else
        echo "file not found: $1"
        exit 1
fi

ffmpeg_preamble="ffmpeg -hide_banner -i '$videofile' -filter_complex \""

duration=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "$videofile")

cutfilters=""
concatfilter=""

for cutno in $( seq 1 $SUBCLIPS ); do
    cut=$(echo "(1 / ($SUBCLIPS+1)) * $cutno" | bc -l)
    let cutchar=$cutno+96 # ascii value so we get max 26 cuts rather than 10
    cutletter=$(printf "\x$(printf %x $cutchar)")
    cutpos=$(echo "$duration * $cut" |bc)
    cutfilters=$(printf "%s[0:v]trim=start=%f:duration=%f,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[%sv];" "$cutfilters" "$cutpos" "$cliplength" "$cutletter")
    cutfilters=$(printf "%s[0:a]atrim=start=%f:duration=%f,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[%sa];" "$cutfilters" "$cutpos" "$cliplength" "$cutletter")
    concatfilter=$(printf "%s[%sv][%sa]" "$concatfilter" "$cutletter" "$cutletter")
done

# concat the cuts together

concatfilter=$(printf "%sconcat=n=%s:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" "$concatfilter" "$SUBCLIPS")

ffmpeg_webmopts=" -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis "
ffmpeg_postscript="\" -map [outv] -map [outa] $ffmpeg_webmopts '$OUTPUTFILE'"

# Chance to cancel before we start

printf "***(hit ctrl+c to cancel)***\n\nExecuting: %s%s%s%s\n" "$ffmpeg_preamble" "$cutfilters" "$concatfilter" "$ffmpeg_postscript"
sleep 3
eval $(echo "$ffmpeg_preamble $cutfilters $concatfilter $ffmpeg_postscript")
```

Comment: I have written a script to automate the bonus part, once it has been tidied up I will edit this answer to include that

Comment: Thank you! Got it with this :). Took the duration with ffprobe, then just added variables plus calculated the times (doing this with php). Works great, many thanks again!

Comment: Happy to help, it was an interesting exercise for me- I have't written a script to generate a filtergraph! If you're doing this in php and performance is more critical than exact durations, you might want to consider using seeks and temporary files to cut+join (but that's probably a separate question)

Comment: I will definitely look into that in that case, yes indeed performance is critical for me. This works like a dream but it does take it's sweet time to run even on powerful server.

Comment: Agreed, it does take quite a while. In that case, I may test seeking + stream copying the subclips and then transcoding. If it results in a noticable difference I will post a self-answer question and link it from here :)